# Selecting multiple fields from <option> and adding them to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

***Background:***

I am creating a three tier e commerce website which sells books. Within my website I have created a form (only accessible to staff members) which allows the staff member to add a new book to the system (the database).

At the moment I have a table within my database which records the following data:

```
book_isdn // unique identifier of each book.
book_cat
book_title
book_author
etc..
```

Along with this, I have created a table for book categories which stores the following:

```
cat_id
cat_title
```

I have defined the following rows in the categories table:

```
cat_id 1 = Business books
cat_id 2 = Computing books
cat_id 3 = Science books
cat_id 4 = History books
etc
```

***The problem:***

In the form which allows a staff member to add a new book, I have a  list:

```
 <select multiple name="b_category" style = "width:150px" required>
 <?php
       $get_cats = "select * from categories";
       $run_cats = mysqli_query($connect, $get_cats);

  while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {

     $cat_id    = $row_cats['cat_id'];
     $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];

    echo "<option value='$cat_id'> $cat_title </option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

I want to add a new book to the 'books' table with the corresponding cat_id for the category to which the book belongs to (i.e. business, computing etc.).

However, a book can also be in two categories, i.e. a book can be both in the field of business and computing.

***The question:***

How can I alter the form so that it selects multiple options from  and adds them to the database, along with the cat_id?

For example:

if using the form I complete all other fields and select computing and business from the list, I want it so that upon clicking "Add new book", the form data is sent to the 'books' table where I will be able to see the new book and under the field of book_cat, I will see 1,2.

I am completely stumped. Is there any way to approach this issue? I hope I have explained this well.

Thanks.

Comment: The select element name has to be `name="b_category[]"`, so that PHP will actually generate an _array_ of the chosen values. But you should not store those as a comma-separated string into one field – but rather _normalize_ your database properly. (That means an extra table where you insert one record each for each combination of book and category id. You might want to add an additional `id` column to your book table as well, so that you do not have to use the long ISBN for this secondary table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's start with something you have not asked for.

a) DB design

Please do not store a concatenated id value like `1,2` in `book_cat`.
That makes lookups and search hard, because you need to fetch & split every single time. That might only work for really small systems.

What you are looking for is a relation table from books to categories.

Name it like this `books_to_categories`, with `book_id` and `cat_id`.

Query: `SELECT cat_id FROM books_to_categories WHERE book_id = 2`;

Result: array one or more ids, then resolve the `cat_id` to it's name (`cat_title`) via the `category` table.

The keyword here is database normalization.

b) Formular

Ok, you have a drop down list box, where you can do multiple selections.
Now, the values of these selections need to be transfered to the server side.
One trick is to use array syntax, instead of

`<select name="b_category" size=4 multiple>`

just use

`<select name="b_category[]" size=4 multiple>`

and on the server-side `var_dump($_POST['b_category']);` to see the values received. Then simply iterate over the values of the array and make your database entries.